# Multiprocessing with multiprocessing.Pool

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I am having issue with even the most basic task using mutiprocessing.Tool method.
It seems to be working but never finish the simplest task.
Could you please help what am I doing wrong?
I read some articles, tried to understand it, but could figure it out. I added a short example (with list(map(squared, range(2_000_000))), it works, but not the below.)
Thanks in advance,

Roland

```
"""
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time
process_pool = Pool(processes = 4)

def squared(n):
    return n ** 2
    
start = time.perf_counter()
process_pool.apply(squared, range(2_000_000))
end = time.perf_counter() - start
print(f"Run time: {end}")
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a case of multithread..... Have you tried something like:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
num_of_threads = 50  # Number of threads executing at the same time
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_of_threads) as executor:
    tasks = []
    for i in i_list:
        tasks.append(
            executor.submit(
                <Function_to_execute>, i
            )
        )

    for future in as_completed(tasks):
        if future.result():
            yield future.result()  # Here can be just a return, yield you return a generator
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `imap()` (and move `squared()` before you define the Pool):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time


def squared(n):
    return n ** 2

process_pool = Pool(processes = 4)
    
start = time.perf_counter()
process_pool.imap(squared, range(2))
end = time.perf_counter() - start
print(f"Run time: {end}")
```

just keep in mind this is not a very representative example, since you dont do anything with the results; something better would be

```
with Pool(4) as pool:
    results = pool.imap(squared, range(2_000_000))

    for result in results:
        pass  # do something here with the result
```